# how to obtain correctly data from query sql

Tags: sql

i'm trying to get data from tables and i want all the catastros that do not have an account, in case it is a deleted account and the catastros is not in another account also show it but i think my query is wrong for any reason:

```
SELECT *
FROM cat_catastros
LEFT JOIN inm_cuenta_catastro ON inm_cuenta_catastro.catastro_id = cat_catastros.id
LEFT JOIN inm_cuentas ON inm_cuenta_catastro.cuenta_id = inm_cuentas.id
WHERE inm_cuentas.deleted_at is not null or inm_cuenta_catastro.cuenta_id is null
```

Tables:

[image]

This no show error but i think that my query are not ok

Comment: Sample data (as text tables), desired results, and a tag for the database you are using would all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want all `catastros` that have no non-deleted account.  That suggests `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cat_catastros c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM inm_cuenta_catastro icc JOIN 
                       inm_cuentas ic
                       ON icc.cuenta_id = ic.id
                  WHERE cc.catastro_id = c.id AND
                        ic.deleted_at is not null 
                 );
```

Your query is not correct.  For instance, it will return any catastros with a deleted account, regardless of whether or not they have other accounts.

Comment: i wanna all catastros that non have an account or in case the account has been deleted and the catastros is not in another account also show it